# How can I programatically tell if my package was built using --release or --debug

Tags: cordova

I am trying to create some code that will change how certain functions act based on release/debug flags. I referenced the current cordova documentation for the build [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-build-command), but there doesn't seem to be any specifics on what else those flags do.

There doesn't appear to be anything useful in the cordova, or device objects.

How can I, programmatically determine what type of build is currently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cordova-plugin-is-debug`

```
cordova.plugins.IsDebug.getIsDebug(function(isDebug) {
    console.log('Is debug:', isDebug);
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: My cordova object does not have `plugins` at all, I'm using `cordova-android@6.4.0` Do you know what release that was added in?

Comment: Cordova doesn't include plugins, you have to install the plugin with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-is-debug`.

Comment: Thanks! It's weird how reading the entire answer changed my results. Let this be a lesson to me...

Comment: Nah, maybe it was a bit unclear as I didn't say use "cordova-plugin-is-debug" plugin, as plugin is part of the plugin name.